# cursor.copy_from failed in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2, sqlbulkcopy

I am facing problems in coping data from one db to another db here is python code.

```
import psycopg2

db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='xx' password='xx' host='127.0.0.2'")
st = db.cursor();

db_l = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xx' user='xx' password='xx' host='127.0.0.1'")
st_l = db_l.cursor();


q = "create table tarf as select i_rate, i_tariff As id, prefix, price_1, price_n, interval_1, interval_n, '00:00' AS start_time, '23:59:59' AS end_time, activation_dat
e, '3049-1-1 00:00' as exp  from rates JOIN tariffs USING (i_tariff) JOIN billing_plans USING(i_tariff) JOIN accounts using (i_billing_plan)"

st_l.execute(q)

f = open('tariff.sql','w')
st_l.copy_to(f,'tarf',sep=',')

st.copy_from(f,'tariff',sep=',')
```

Here is an error faced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sync_tariff.py", line 23, in <module>
    st.copy_from(f,'tariff',sep=',')
psycopg2.extensions.QueryCanceledError: COPY from stdin failed: error in .read() call
CONTEXT:  COPY tariff, line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the file and then open it for reading

```
f = open('tariff.sql', 'w')
st_l.copy_to(f, 'tarf', sep=',')

f.close()

f = open('tariff.sql', 'r')
st.copy_from(f, 'tariff', sep=',')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can I have a way not to write data to disk and transfer from st_l to st like FileStream in c#, and one thing thats is important is: cursor.copy_to does not support query but table name and creating temp table from query to copy_to takes upto 23 seconds while "\copy (query) TO 'filepath'" on psql takes around 10 seconds is there any way to use query in cursor.copy_to. I Have used this by emulating terminal but thats not a recommended practice?

Comment: @sharafjaffri Are you using python just for the data transfer? You could use dblink or psql piping. Open another question about it.